# How to view brotli compressed files on browser?

Tags: node.js, server, compression, brotli

I'm trying to static serve brotli compressed files. I was able to compress files with this code:

```js
// node.js
const compressStream = require("iltorb").compressStream;
const fs = require("fs");

const wrr = fs.createWriteStream("index-b.html");

fs.createReadStream("index.html")
  .pipe(compressStream())
  .pipe(wrr);
```

So now the `index-b.html` file is compressed. But how can I see this on browser?

When I go to that page, this is what I'm seeing:

[image]

I thought the browser will understand this is a brotli encoded file. But it didn't. When I looked at the response headers,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: ecstatic-3.3.1
cache-control: max-age=3600
last-modified: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 17:27:32 GMT
etag: W/"281474976993459-334-2019-04-06T17:27:32.047Z"
content-length: 334
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 17:36:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

there was no encoding set. How can I address this?

Comment: Show the rest of your Node.js code.

Comment: there are no any remaining code. I put that compressed file in a folder and started a server with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in that folder. Then went to browser. @BarryPollard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which is a very simple HTTP server and does not allow you to set content-encoding explicitly.

It looks like there is [an issue raised to add Brotli support](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/445), but it has not been completed yet. Even if it was, it is only intended to serve static, pre-compressed files (assuming it will be implemented the same as the `--gzip` option).

To use dynamic brotli like you want, you have to use the normal Node [http.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) code or something like [express](https://expressjs.com/).